# Negative results using kenlm

Tags: python, language-model

I am new to the language modeling and a make a 3grams language model using  [kenlm](http://victor.chahuneau.fr/notes/2012/07/03/kenlm.html)(or [this](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/estimation/)) from a large text file (~7gb.).
I make a binary file from my language model and call it in python like this:

```
import kenlm
model = kenlm.LanguageModel(<my .klm file>)
model.score(<my sentence>)
```

and i get a negative number as the result.and when i change the sentence for scoring, the result remains negative but changes.I give it exactly one of the large text file sentences but it gives me a bad negative number(in comparison with a sentence that does not in the text file)
I dont know what does negative result means and how can i convert it to positive and normal result to select the most correct sentece between some sentences.

Comment: I have a doubt, I saw kenlm documentation, however the training method in python is nowhere mentioned. How can we train our model?

Comment: same problem. I think the respondents miss the point of @Emad Helmi's question. Why does a sentence drawn verbatim from the corpus return a bad negative number

Answer (score 3):

The final negative number say, -9.585592 is the log probability of the sentence. Since it's the logarithm, you need to compute the 10 to the power of that number, which is around 2.60 x 10-10. Maybe this is the positive number you are looking for.

More info [here](http://masatohagiwara.net/training-an-n-gram-language-model-and-estimating-sentence-probability.html)

Answer (score 3):

To get the corresponding score that is between 0 and 1:

```
import math
print(math.pow(10,model.score(<my sentence>)))
```